# "Особые" дети

Tags: кавычки

Нужны ли кавычки при употреблении слова "особые" в смысле инвалидности? Такие дети же действительно особые...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У слова "Особый'' одно из значений: ''Не похожий на других, не такой, как все; необычный, особенный''. Дети-инвалиды тоже особые, не похожие на все. Поэтому в вашем примере кавычки не нужны.